# Selecting an element based on the child inner text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a script which adds a filter field to the top of each column. However, there's a column called "Type" that I'm trying to get it to skip. For example in the image below there's a type field with pdf icons. I'm trying to prevent a textfield from being added to this column.

This is the script:

```
$(this).children("th,td").each(function()
        {
            if($(this).hasClass("ms-vh-icon") ||
            $(this).hasClass("ms-vh-group") )
            {
                // attachment + Group (SLN)
                tdset += "<td></td>";
            }
            else
            {
                // filterable
                tdset += "<td><input type='text' class='vossers-filterfield' filtercolindex='" + colIndex + "' placeholder='Filter...'/></td>";                 
            }

            colIndex++;
        });
```

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TacXD.png):

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "I have a script which adds an input field to table cells"? And what's the text we're looking for?

Comment: Oh yea sorry, ill update OP. I'm trying to prevent it from adding a textbox to the "Type" column. This column returns an image icon which users can't filter by.

Comment: Oh, it adds a field to the top of each column.

Comment: Right under the title it will add a textbox. There's an if condition that determines where, I'm hoping to add to the condition to not do it for a column which as a child anchor tag with innerText = Type.

Comment: Can you add the relevant (minimal/[sscce](http://sscce.org/)) code (HTML and JavaSCript/jQuery) to your question? A *picture* of code isn't as helpful as you might think, it may paint a thousand words, but it does so very imprecisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the anchor with that text using this

```
if ($(this).find('a').text()=='Type')
```

but it could be that there are spaces in the text so you would need to trim or use replace or a regex to make sure you're catching it, for example

```
var $a=$(this).find('a'); // add empty to prevent null
if ($a.length && $a.text().replace('Type', '')!=$a.text())...
```

But having seen at the code it seems you can just search for `#diidSortDocIcon`

```
tdset='';
$(this).children("th,td").each(function(colIndex){
    if ($(this).find('#diidSortDocIcon').length || $(this).is('.ms-vh-icon, .ms-vh-group')){
        tdset += "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    }else{
        tdset += "<td><input type='text' class='vossers-filterfield' filtercolindex='" + colIndex + "' placeholder='Filter...'/></td>";
    }
});
```

You can also set colIndex in the each rather than use `colIndex++` and you hadn't set `tdset='';`

http://jsfiddle.net/v7brU/2/

Comment: So I tried the $(this).children('a').text()=='Type' but It still placed an input field under type. I'll try to add more of the code.

Comment: If you can post enough HTML to make it work in a jsfiddle that would be useful. Also need to mention `colIndex` when this issue is fixed.

Comment: I don't mind posting the JS used to filter, the problem is the HTML. It's a SharePoint page and the html is massive.

Comment: Here's the fiddle, the html is all messed up though. THat's why I posted in a picture. http://jsfiddle.net/v7brU/

Comment: That's fine. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Had to tweak a bit, should be just be  + colIndex +  then at the end of the if colIndex++  other than that, seems to be work good. Thank you very much.

Comment: colIndex is automatically incremented by the each iteration.